# πόρνος refer to Esau in Hebrews 12:16?

Tags: greek, word-study, hebrews

(KJV)Hebrews 12:16

> Lest there be any ***fornicator,*** or profane person, as Esau, who for one morsel of meat sold his birthright.

Hebrews 12:16

> μή τις ***πόρνος*** ἢ βέβηλος ὡς ἠσαῦ, ὃς ἀντὶ βρώσεως μιᾶς ἀπέδετο τὰ πρωτοτόκια ἑαυτοῦ.

Does the disjunctive seperate the two words fornicator & profane or both of them refer to Esau in the above text?

Answer (score 2):

Esau, like [Lamech](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis_4:19,23?&version=KJV&interface=print) before him, had two wives ([Genesis 26:34](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis_26:34?&version=KJV&interface=print)). Unlike Abraham or Jacob, there does not seem to have been any mitigating factor for this (such as [barrenness](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis_16:1-2?&version=KJV&interface=print) or [deceit](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis_29:16-30?&version=KJV&interface=print)). Though not technically considered a sin during Old Testament days, it seems to have fallen out of use by Paul's time ([1 Corinthians 7:2](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1_Corinthians_7:2?&version=KJV&interface=print); [1 Timothy 3:2 & 12](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1_Timothy_3:2,12?&version=KJV&interface=print); [Titus 1:6](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Titus_1:6?&version=KJV&interface=print)). So the word *fornicator* does indeed appear to apply to Esau, the use of *or* rather than *and* being explained by the fact that both categories mentioned in the verse are types of Esau, i.e., one doesn't have to be *both* to embody his character (or rather his *lack* thereof).